# EF Core - automatically create DbContext class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there any CLI command or Visual Studio extension to create `ApplicationDBContext` class automatically from `Models` folder where my model classes are located: 'User', 'Product', 'Account'?

Result of the CLI command or extension should be:

[image]

Comment: Not from your entity classes alone, no - to my knowledge EF Core only supports scaffolding from actual databases ("code first from database").

Comment: maybe you know any Visual studio extension for it? I can't find it

Comment: Personally I use database-first scaffolding, this is my go-to script: https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator (disclaimer: I'm a contributor to it)

Comment: You don't *need* db set properties. You could scan your assembly to define your model, then call `.Set<T>()`. But I don't think the tradeoff is that worthwhile.

Comment: @DeveloperMister Hello, what database do you use?

Comment: I'm using ms sql server

Comment: @DeveloperMister Why not try reverse engineering to automatically generate the DBContext class?

Comment: Look at the [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) - reverse engineering from an existing database, creates your model and dbcontext classes - highly recommended

Comment: @marc_s I Power tools is great! but I do not have db. I have models folder with classes and unfortunately I can't decide which eproach use in my job

Comment: @DeveloperMister I don't quite understand what you're describing as a model folder with classes. Can you be more specific? It is best to add pictures.